# How to setup cron expression c correctly for quartz job?

Tags: cron, quartz

I'm trying to schedule a quartz job for a specific time on a day. This is the  cron
expression:

```
0 20 18 ?  * * *
```

It should fire on 18:20 every day, instead the next fire time show:

```
2021-08-29T08:20:00.000+00:00
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this cron expression:

```
20 18 * * *
```

Also suggest this cron calculator [site](https://crontab.guru/).